# Is every vector bundle over an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ flat?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Can every smooth, real vector bundle over an open subset $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be equipped with a flat connection? Intuitively I feel the answer is "yes", but I don't know how to prove this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the tangent space $TS^2$ of the $2$-sphere $S^2$ is not flat since the Euler characteristic of $S^2$ is not zero. You have a map from $H_t:R^3-\{0\}\rightarrow R^3-\{0\}$ defined $H_t(x)=(1-t)x+{{tx}\over{t\|x\|}}, t\in [0,1].$ $H$ is a deformation retract of $R^3-\{0\}$ to $S^2$ and $H_t(x)=x$, if  $x\in \{x:\|x\|=1\}=S^2$. The pullback of $TS^2$ by $H_t$ $R^3-\{0\}$ is not flat. If it was flat, its restriction to $S^2$ which is $TS^2$ would have been flat and this is not true.

Comment: But $R^3-\{0\}$ is an open subset of $R^3$.